# Java "'.class' expected" for return statement

Tags: java, return-value, command-prompt, identifier

I am trying to write a simple Java program which calculates the invoice amount for parts ordered from a hardware store. Once I compile it through the command prompt, I receive "Invoice.java:17: error: '.class' expected
return int invoiceAmount;"

Did I miss an identifier somewhere? I've tried adding datatypes and new methods to instantiate and display the invoiceAmount again, but that did not seem to work. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
//Invoice for hardware store

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Invoice { 
  public static void setInvoice(String[] args) {

    String partNumber;
    String partDescription;
    double price;
    Scanner amountPurchased = new Scanner(System.in);

  }

  public double getInvoiceAmount(){ 
    return int invoiceAmount;       
  }

  private void setInvoice(int amountPurchased){
    int amountPurchased;

    // get quantity of item from user input 
    System.out.println("Please enter quantity of item purchased: ");
    amountPurchased = amountPurchased.nextInt( );

    // get item price from user input   
    System.out.println("Please enter single unit item price: ");
    Scanner price = new Scanner(System.in);

    //multiplies quantity by price per item
    invoiceAmount = amountPurchased * price;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want `return int invoiceAmount;` to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple errors in your code:

- there is no `public static void main(String[] args)` method so program cannot run
- after `return` statement you shoud use variable's name and not type+variable's name
- in `setInvoice` method you redefine variable `amountPurchased`
- there is no object and no object's fields so you cannot save your results into them

[Here is few materials to help you with java language and object concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)

Hope I helped a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I forgot to mention that I had created a test class to include the main method.